# Should questions about tvOS also be tagged iOS?

Tags: support, tags

I just edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32792329/tvos-creating-parallax-effect-on-uicollectionviewcell) because it pertained solely to tvOS but was also tagged with the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag. My question is, should the close relation between the two platforms mean that questions can be tagged with both tags, perhaps in order to attract more attention, or should they only be tagged with the platform that the question is specifically about?

Comment: Tags are not so the question is viewed more, but for classification. Would an expert in ios answer that question? If not, it's not related to ios, so no need for the tag

Comment: I think an expert in iOS would be well prepared to answer questions on tvOS, seeing as they are source compatible and share most of the frameworks.

Comment: It really depends. Some questions about frameworks shared between tvOS and iOS work but the majority of the time both tags aren't suitable. The real problem is when questions include both apple-tv and tvOS tags.

Answer (score -2):

Only tag it with what would be the common denomination with similar questions.

If both iOS and tvOS share the same context, tag it with the corresponding common context instead (if they are relevant)! That would mean that if it's a tvOS question, using  Xcode (IDE), and Objective-C, as language with Swift framework are relevant, use them. Which is the same Patrice describe on [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306849/should-questions-about-tvos-also-be-tagged-ios/311033#comment251450_306849). **Don't use tag just to give more views**, but keep them tightly relevant to the question.

Comment: Terrible suggestion.
Last time I checked there were dozens of frameworks, which are relevant for iOS and mobile products only, and that is about Apple frameworks only. 
To make things worse, there are framework with the same name, but with slight and not so slight different implementation, e.g. on OS X and iOS. I wish I could down vote you more 
:-)

Comment: @MicheleGiuseppeFadda how many frameworks can be involved in a single task? If there are more than 3 then the question is obviously too broad (that or Apple sucks). I can have a question about doing something on a target device without specifying the framework, but that would be most likely closed as too broad too. In summary, target device + framework if any is used on the original problem should suffice.

Comment: How many frameworks should a developer browse through in Stack Overflow? Then add misspellings, dual tagging: no, no and no.

Comment: @MicheleGiuseppeFadda what? Are you implying that someone just don't google "how to remove the last word on a string ios" and be done with it?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, Objective-C and Swift are programming languages - these are not frameworks at all. tvOS and iOS do share some frameworks, but these frameworks don't necessarily share the same set of properties and methods on both systems. Anyway, tvOS is its own OS, and the tag should be used for any question about tvOS.

Comment: @EricD. but obviously it shouldn't use ios tag, right? That's what my answer is saying.

Comment: Indeed, tvOS ≠ iOS, despite many similarities. // Your asnwer doesn't say that, no. You may want to edit it.

Comment: @EricD. question? What question? The question this answers says "should the close relation between the two platforms mean that questions can be tagged with both tags" to which I respond "Only tag it with what would be the common denomination with similar questions".

Comment: `If both iOS and tvOS share the same framework, tag it with the framework instead` is very different from `but obviously it shouldn't use ios tag, right? That's what my answer is saying`. So I thought, no, your answer is not saying that. :)

Comment: @EricD. when I said "framework" I meant it in the [common meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/framework), not the software related, like "structure". Blame that to my economics background.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for editing your answer. I really think it makes more sense now and is a better reflection of what you meant. // I still disagree with it, though, but that's a different topic. :) What I disagree with is your `instead`. I think we should tag what is relevant to the question: the framework if there's one, the language if it's relevant, the specifics of the question... without getting rid of the platform tag which is very important for classification and actually plays the role of the common ground.

Comment: @EricD. I'm not even sure what are you gathering from it. If it's relevant to tvos, use that tag. If it's relevant to tvos and something else, use those.

Comment: I would agree with: `If it's relevant to tvos, use that tag. If it's relevant to tvos and something else, use those *too*`. When I read your answer, not so much, for the reasons I've exposed.

Comment: @EricD. again, what reasons are you exposing? Your reasons (?) you are disagreeing are exactly the ones I'm loathing with extreme prejudice on my answer. If you have to put my answer on a single phrase is: tag it with what is relevant to the question.

Comment: What you're missing is the importance of `instead` in your answer, and the fact that I'm disagreeing on this point precisely. // Thanks for the edit. There's no more confusion.

Comment: The first sentence is correct, the rest is iffy. Questions that should actually be tagged [tag:xcode] are rather rare. See the guidance in its excerpt.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I used the conditional "if ... [they[ ... are relevant, use them", I'm not saying that all questions about xcode would need the tag, but only on those cases where is absolutely relevant.

Answer (score -5):

I would say that you should dual tag it perhaps.  `watchOS` and `tvOS` share a good portion of their functionality with `iOS` and as such ... its hard to say.